# Rewire in igraph for R meaning of niter parameter

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph, statistics-bootstrap, network-analysis

For a network g (as below), what is the practical meaning of the niter parameter in the `igraph::rewire` function

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

g <- sample_smallworld(1, 10, 3, 0.05)
```

For example if I would run:

```
g1 <- g %>%
     rewire(keeping_degseq(niter = 20))

g2 <- g %>%
     rewire(keeping_degseq(niter = 100))
```

I do see differences between the two networks on a network property level (e.g. betweenness centrality), but I'm not sure which value is the most appropriate if I want to do bootstrapping on my network for example. The reason why I don't know which value to choose comes as well as I don't really understand what does the niter parameter do.

Comment: `niter` refers to the number-of-iterations. From the help page: `[The mode] can be one of the following: simple: simple rewiring algorithm which chooses two arbitrary edges in each step (namely (a,b) and (c,d)) and substitutes them with (a,d) and (c,b) if they don't yet exist`. This suggests to me that `rewiring` is performed by iteratively swapping edges until `niter` edges are swapped.

Comment: @CPak indeed. I actually made a mistake on my previous edit. The higher the niter the more edges you swap. But I wonder if it does swap or if it creates new edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will randomly switch edges like this:

[image]
              
[image]

The switch is performed only if it wouldn't result in multi-edges.

`niter` specifies the number of trials.  Some of the trials will not be successful.

Thus @CPak's statement in the comment that `niter` edges will be swapped is not correct.  Actually, `niter` attempts will be made.

This is explained in the documentation:

http://igraph.org/r/doc/keeping_degseq.html 
http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Generators.html#igraph_rewire

Comment: Indeed. That's the idea I had. I ran some tests to see how many different edges we get even if we have a `niter = ecount(g)*10`, and it never reaches 100%. Usually it goes around 98% or so. But it's really interesting the schematic you've posted here. I wonder if there's more mathematics to it I can get. Unfortunately the links aren't really clear on that side.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira Switches like this are commonly used when dealing with graphs having a certain degree sequence either computationally or theoretically. They're also called "edge swaps".